# CreateJS' PreloadJS progress event inaccurate

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I'm trying to load some assets using the PreloadJS class from the CreateJS suite, but when very first progress event fired reports `e.loaded` and `e.progress` as `0.83`, the numbers then decrease over the next few event before finally going back up again.

```
t.assets = new createjs.LoadQueue();
t.assets.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
t.assets.setMaxConnections(10);
t.assets.addEventListener("progress", function(e){
    console.log(e.loaded);
});
t.assets.addEventListener("complete", function(){
    callback();                                          
});
t.assets.loadManifest([
    { id: 'facebook_btn', src: 'img/ingame/facebook_white_btn.png' },
    { id: 'twitter_btn', src: 'img/ingame/twitter_white_btn.png' },
    { id: 'embed_btn', src: 'img/ingame/embed_white_btn.png' },
]);
```

I get these results in the console

```
0.8333333333333334
0.7142857142857143
0.625
0.5555555555555556
0.5
0.45454545454545453
0.4984983736293216
0.5894074645384125
0.6363636363636364
0.6663361591119469
0.7572452500210378
0.8261679748749072
0.9170770657839982
0.9390634318392196
1
```

Is this because it's working through the manifest initally and doesn't take into account everything right away?

Is checking the the progress is going the correct way before displaying these results in a preloader a good method of making sure it's sorted itself out?

Comment: This is a bizarre behaviour. PreloadJS would slot off 1/3 of the progress for each item (regardless of size), and then fill in each segment with the bytesLoaded of each item. You should not see what you showed in your report. Any chance you can send some code over on the community site? http://community.createjs.com. Even just the assets you are loading would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the manifest is just providing a convienient way to deal with a batch of assets without you having to loop through them yourself. Have a look at the code, it's almost the same as the loadFile method, but loops through the array of objects. So it's not doing anything fancy in terms of better calculating the progress.

http://createjs.com/Docs/PreloadJS/files/.._src_preloadjs_LoadQueue.js.html#l898

You have a couple options though to make it look more accurate.

1. If you're not loading much and it's only going to take a few seconds you might just want to not use the progress event. Instead you can just catch load errors or other hangups.
2. If you are loading lots of things and it could take some time then consider waiting a few seconds before displaying the progress. That gives the manifest time to add enough stuff that it should just be moving in a positive direction towards 1.